# Why I must double quote the schema name and the table name in order to query from an Oracle table?

Tags: oracle

I'm new in Oracle and I got the following issue. Why I must double quote the schema name and the table name in order to query from a table? Are there any setting to change it?

Thanks.

```
SQL> conn sys/ogrish@orcl as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> select * from m.album;
select * from m.album
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from M.Album where rownum < 2;
select * from M.Album where rownum < 2;
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

SQL> select * from "M"."Album" where rownum < 2;

   AlbumId Title
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 For Those About To Rock We Salute You

SQL> conn m/m@orcl
Connected.
SQL> select table_name from user_tables;

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
Album
Artist
Customer
Employee
Genre
Invoice
InvoiceLine
MediaType
Playlist
PlaylistTrack
sysdiagrams

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
Track

12 rows selected.

SQL> select * from album where rownum < 2;
select * from album where rownum < 2;
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from Album where rownum < 2;
select * from Album where rownum < 2
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from m.album where rownum < 2;
select * from m.album where rownum < 2
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from M.Album where rownum < 2;
select * from M.Album where rownum < 2
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from "M"."Album" where rownum < 2;

   AlbumId Title
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 For Those About To Rock We Salute You

SQL> select * from "Album" where rownum < 2;

   AlbumId Title
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 For Those About To Rock We Salute You

SQL>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to add double quote on the schema name, but you have to do it on the table name since you created it with quotes (which made it case-sensitive):

```
select * from M."Album"
```

should work too. Otherwise M.Album is translated by default to M.ALBUM - and the table ALBUM does not exist.

Comment: Thanks alfasin. If I already have this kind of tables, can I change the name of them to case insensitive mode?

Comment: sure: `RENAME TABLE M."Album" TO M.ALBUM;` read more [*here*](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljrenametablestatement.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the need for the pre-fixing the schema name by using synonyms.